# StackOverflowError while using Android Calendar's setMinDate()

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

[image: screen of my problem]

refer to the error shown in the image above.

This problem is shown when I set `calendarView.setMinDate`
and I can't solve I am facing this problem when I use the calender

> Background concurrent copying GC freed 98234(2MB) AllocSpace objects,
>   1(1564KB) LOS objects, 41% free, 34MB/58MB, paused 139us total
>   366.099ms

**here is my code**

```
 public class select_time extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.calendarView)
    CalendarView calendarView;
    DatesView datesView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_time);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        in = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("in", true);
        datesView = new DatesView(findViewById(R.id.datesView));
        datesView.setOnCalenderClick(new DatesView.onClenderClick() {
            @Override
            public void OnClick(boolean in) {
                setWanted(in);
            }
        });
        datesView.refresh(this);
        refreshCalendar();
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("data", 0);
                prefs.edit().putLong((in ? "in" : "out") + "_date", calendar.getTimeInMillis()).apply();
                if (in) {
                    if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() == out_date.getTime() || calendar.getTimeInMillis() >= out_date.getTime()) {
                        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                        prefs.edit().putLong("out_date", calendar.getTimeInMillis()).apply();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() == out_date.getTime() || calendar.getTimeInMillis() <= out_date.getTime()) {
                        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                        prefs.edit().putLong("in_date", calendar.getTimeInMillis()).apply();
                    }
                }
                datesView.refresh(select_time.this);
            }
        });
    }
    Date in_date,out_date;
    public void refreshCalendar(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("data", 0);
        in_date = new Date(prefs.getLong("in_date", 0));
        out_date = new Date(prefs.getLong("out_date", 0));
        calendarView.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        calendarView.setDate(in ? in_date.getTime() : out_date.getTime());
        setWanted(in);

    }
    boolean in;
    public void setWanted(boolean in) {
        this.in = in;
        datesView.check_in.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(in ? R.color.gray : R.color.white));
        datesView.check_out.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(!in ? R.color.gray : R.color.white));
        refreshCalendar();
    }
    public void clickDone(View view) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with using Calender?

Comment: This because somewhere in there recursion is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `setWanted(in);` from `refreshCalendar()` and also calling `refreshCalendar();` from `setWanted(boolean in)`.  This creates an infinite call loop, which eventually exhausts the stack.  You need to remove one of those two calls.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because you are calling `refreshCalendar();` in setWanted, which is called in the calenderOnChange, which then is again called with `datesView.refresh` which is why you are calling it again and again, so you need to remove this loop.
Probably with removing the `refreshCalendar();` in setWanted.